# How to implement full disk encryption on Linux?

Tags: linux, disk-encryption

The only reason why I don't use Linux (even though I prefer Linux over Windows, and can do everything faster and more efficiently) is because each time I try to learn about dm-crypt I give up.

Can someone point me in the right direction for full OTFE on Linux (like TrueCrypt)?

Comment: Why not just use TrueCrypt?

Comment: TrueCrypt doesn't work on system partitions in linux

Comment: I'm not a TrueCrypt guru, but I'm pretty sure it does.

Comment: I am not a TrueCrypt guru, and with experience and visiting TrueCrypts website, that it does not work w/ linux system partitions. Please stop trying to argue my point; also I stated clearly that I want to use dm-crypt

Comment: So what does this mean: "Free open-source disk encryption software for Windows 7/Vista/XP, Mac OS X, and Linux"

Comment: @soandos: There is a difference w/ encrypting a regular disk (that doesn't have boot information, boot files, etc), and then encrypting a system partition.

Comment: If you want to use dm-crypt that is fine, but the way you worded your question made it seem like you were using it because you thought TrueCrypt was not an option.  From what I am reading, TrueCrypt works the same (for the most part) on Linux as it does on Windows.  Check this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1700032).

Comment: I have all features in linux TrueCrypt that I have in windows except for system partition encryption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LUKS can't encrypt the /boot partition, but everything else including your root partition can. That means GRUB and your kernel won't be encrypted, but everything else, including your files, programs, and logs, will.

This is similar to how TrueCrypt works. It has its own unencrypted bootloader that decrypts and runs Windows.

Many distributions allow you to encrypt entire partitions during installation.  Fedora does using the normal installer, just check *Encrypt this filesystem* in the partitioning setup.  Ubuntu also permits you to encrypt whole partitions, but you must use their alternate install media to do so.  Live media only supports home directory encryption.